# QSettings simple task not working

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

I'm trying to use QSettings on my code but it's not working correctly. My code is:

```
In Mainwindow.h
QSettings settings
```

(I have declared before all `setOrganizationName setOrganizationDomain 
setApplicationName`)

```
In Mainwindow.cpp
settings.setValue("smtp/email", "test");
qDebug() << settings.value("smtp/email").toString();
```

But the qDebug is returning me `""`

I believe it's a simple use of QSettings but it's not working.

Comment: You might need to call [`settings.sync()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#sync) to make sure all data has been written before reading it back.

Comment: @G.M. I'm afraid it's giving the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency, the changes may not be saved to permanent storage immediately. (You can always call sync() to commit your changes.)

Comment: Try giving organization name and application name for settings. For example: QSettings settings( "MySoft", "Star Runner" );

Comment: It works if I declare the QSettings variable and all the variables like organization name in mainwindow.cpp, the problem comes when dividing everything between files

Comment: Can you show an example? And check the returned value of the organizationName method of the QSetting instance.

Comment: Where am I suposed to declare the orgsnization name and all the other stuff ?

Comment: You could do it after QApplication declaration in the main function

Comment: That was the problem, I was declaring it after the `w.show();` inside `main.cpp`now it's working. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please note that `QSetting`'s [destructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#dtor.QSettings) calls `sync()`. So, All unsaved changes will be written to permanent storage automatically when the `QSettings` object is destructed